# Is there a list of shortcuts which are not reserved in any major browser?

Tags: cross-browser, ux

In the past, when I implemented shortcuts for web applications, I used different ones for different browsers: for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> was used in Chrome, but would be something else, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Firefox, since Firefox reserves the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut for add-ons.

Actually, I have a project where it would be nice to have the same shortcuts for every browser.

Is there a list of shortcuts which are *not* reserved in any major browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE and Opera) or do I have to do my own by listing?

Google wasn't helpful, since it rather shows the list of shortcuts which are common to all major browsers.

Comment: You can use a `CTRL+ALT+SPACE+(...)` prefix

Comment: I would have thought keyboard shortcuts should (must) be consistent across browsers. Unless you use obscure key combinations then I would have thought there is always the possibility of clashes (particularly if you include browser extensions in the mix). But users might not mind if there is a conflict (if your shortcut does indeed override the underlying browser shortcut). Give your users the ability to disable the shortcuts and, ultimately, to customize them.

Comment: @w3d: +1. The inconsistencies were acceptable in previous projects, since the few users who used the shortcuts used the same browser all the time (but yes, if it's possible to be consistent, it's much better). As for the ability to customize the shortcuts, it's an excellent point and an excellent UX suggestion, especially for intranet web apps used 8 hours per day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to be approaching it, this is probably going to be futile. At best, you're going to come up with a very small list of combinations that don't conflict in the *base* browsers, then find out that there are plenty of add-ons that then go ahead and use them which are common enough to be a problem anyway.

You should avoid the standard patterns like <kbd>Ctrl+[letter]</kbd> altogether. There are JS libraries like [Mousetrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) that make this easy. For example, one of its options binds your functions to <kbd>Shift+[foo]</kbd> patterns instead.

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to add that the common approach to this issue is to use key shortcuts without modifiers. Google products use plain text shortcuts, same as Facebook, Trello, and several others.